# JRuby and CLASSPATH in Windows

Tags: jruby

I have installed JRuby 1.6.0 on my Windows XP machine. I have also downloaded the Google gdata libraries. This code:

```
require "java"
$CLASSPATH << "D:\\javalib\\gdata\\java\\lib\\*"
include_class "com.google.gdata.client.docs"
```

gives this error:

```
org/jruby/javasupport/JavaClass.java:1052:in `for_name': cannot load Java class
com.google.gdata.client.docs (NameError)
        from org/jruby/javasupport/JavaUtilities.java:34:in `get_proxy_class'
        from C:/jruby-1.6.0.RC1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/builtin/javasupport/co
re_ext/object.rb:46:in `java_import'
        from C:/jruby-1.6.0.RC1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/builtin/javasupport/co
re_ext/object.rb:26:in `include_class'
        from download_gdocs.rb:5:in `(root)'
```

The Google gdata Java libraries are in `D:\javalib\gdata\java\lib`. For example, if I type `jar tvf D:\javalib\gdata\java\lib\gdata-client-1.0.jar` I get (in part) this:

```
     0 Fri Feb 04 15:25:54 PST 2011 com/google/gdata/data/docs/
   904 Fri Feb 04 15:25:54 PST 2011 com/google/gdata/client/docs/DocsService$Versions.class
  6686 Fri Feb 04 15:25:54 PST 2011 com/google/gdata/client/docs/DocsService.class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$CLASSPATH` doesn't support glob expressions. Instead, `require` each .jar individually:

```
Dir["D:\\javalib\\gdata\\java\\lib\\*.jar"].each { |jar| require jar }
```

Comment: That seems to solve one of my issues. I will post my other problem in a separate post.